# Email encoding with Amazon SES sendRawEmail

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm trying to send the following raw email message generated by PHPMailer 5.2.9 using the SES SDK 2.7 `sendRawEmail` method:

```
Date: Tue, 28 Oct 2014 03:34:18 +0000
From: someemail@gmail.com
Reply-To: someemail@gmail.com
Message-ID: <c738074625a476ed8e2793323ad0b3b2@*.dev>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b1_c738074625a476ed8e2793323ad0b3b2"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
To: someperson@gmail.com
Subject: Test subject (TID #1, SID #2)

--b1_c738074625a476ed8e2793323ad0b3b2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

Test email for _Some One_!


--b1_c738074625a476ed8e2793323ad0b3b2
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii

Test email for <i>Some One</i>!


--b1_c738074625a476ed8e2793323ad0b3b2--
```

Here is the code used to generate the raw email and then send it:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->addAddress($to);
$mail->setFrom($from);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->CharSet = $char_set;
$mail->AltBody = $text;
$mail->Body = $html;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->addAttachment($attachment);

$mail->preSend();

$args = [
    'Source'       => $from,
    'Destinations' => [$to],
    'RawMessage'   => [
        'Data' => $mail->getSentMIMEMessage()
    ]
];

$aws = Aws\Common\Aws::factory(app_path() . '/config/aws.php');

$ses = $aws->get('ses');

$send_result = $ses->sendRawEmail($args);
```

I get no errors in the `$send_result`, just a standard 'MessageId' and 'RequestId' as I would with a successful send (and it does actually send).

I've tried with and without attachments as well, but it still sends the message as a garbled mess. This is what is received:
http://prntscr.com/50ij42

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I've been attempting to send an email with an attachment through SES, with much struggle trying to manually create the MIME structure for the email. Brilliant idea to just use PHPMailer to create it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to encode data:

```
'RawMessage'   => [
    'Data' => base64_encode( $mail->getSentMIMEMessage() )
]
```

From [SDK documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html#_sendRawEmail):
  ...
  - Content must be base64-encoded, if MIME requires it.

Comment: Strange, I read "base64 encoding (if necessary)" so I didn't think that applied to 8-bit encodings. I also thought it only applied to the mime block itself and not the entire email, so when my attachments were base64 encoded themselves I though that would do. This fixed the problem though!

Comment: I agree, the wording is a bit confusing.